# Fastest way to generate hash function from k wise independent hash family for small k(<=5)

Tags: python, random, hash, murmurhash

I need a hash function `h[n]:[t]` from k wise independent hash family when k is small (`<= 5`). Or I need n hash values chosen uniformly randomly from `[1-t]` such that they are [k wise independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-independent_hashing). I am trying to implement some randomized algorithms where I needed this. I was generating  n random number from range `[1-t]` using

`scipy.stats.randint(0,self._t).rvs(self._n)`

but this seems to be too slow for my application. Since I don't need full randomness but only 4 wise independence I was wondering if I could speed this up. I know I can use polynomial hash family to get k wise independence but is this the best? If yes, is there any fast implementation of this which I can plug in? If no, what are the alternative ways (libraries, possibly in Python)?

I have looked at this thread [Obtaining a k-wise independent hash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284317/obtaining-a-k-wise-independent-hash-function) but I am not sure what the accepted answer means by this:
"*if you need k different hash, just re-use the same algorithm k times, with k different seeds*".

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If I am right your goal is to generate `n` random numbers (at least 4-wise independent) in range `[1-t]` in fastest way possible.

Comment: @EngineeredBrain Yes exactly and those number should be uniformly randomly picked from [1-t]. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use numba's `jit` with numpy's `random.randint()`:

```
import scipy.stats
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

def randint_scipy(n):
    return scipy.stats.randint(0, 10000).rvs(n)

def randint_numpy(n):
    return np.random.randint(0, 10000, n)

@jit
def randint_numpy_jit(n):
    return np.random.randint(0, 10000, n)

%timeit randint_scipy(5)
%timeit randint_numpy(5)
%timeit randint_numpy_jit(5)
```

Output:

```
1.09 ms ± 10.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
4.63 µs ± 149 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
960 ns ± 50.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Thus, **numpy + numba is 1135 times faster** than scipy's implementation of `randint()`.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to get a real k-wise independent hash function is to evaluate a degree-k polynomial over a finite field.
The fastest way to do that is probably using carry less multiplication.
For example, code see https://github.com/speedyhash/shorthash/blob/master/include/clhash.h#L248

In general, you should see the Techniques section on the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-independent_hashing#Techniques